# Difference between ng-model="xxx" and value="{{xxx}}"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a regular form, when a `reset` type button (`<button type="reset">Reset</button>`) is clicked, all input controls will be emptied except `readonly` or `disabled`.

http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/K2f7g/

When constructing a form using `angular`, I have

```
<input type="text" id="district" disabled="" ng-model="address.district" />
```

In this form, when the `reset` button is clicked, the value in the input above is removed even it is marked as `disabled` or `readonly`. Why? Should I use `ng-model` to bind to this input control? Do I have to use `value=` to make the binding?

```
<input type="text" id="district" disabled="" value="{{address.district}}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` adds parsing and validation. Just interpolating the value isn't sufficient for that.

In your fiddle, you denote a field as `required`. `required` is also another directive that works with `ngModelController`.

Comment: So my understanding is, for disabled or readonly input, we should use `value="{{xxx}}", since the value won't change anyway. But is there a way we can use `ng-model` and enjoy all the benefit of validation, but still make it truly `readonly` (won't be wiped by the reset button)?

Comment: why not just use a span for that instead of a form field?

Comment: Fine. That'll definitely work. But just curious, `ng-model` would void the `readonly` and `disabled` attributes in my case. No fix for that, is it?

Comment: @Blaise you would have to try.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-model` supports 2-way data binding. When you use `ng-model` the value of the model is bound to the view and updating the model will update the view and vice-versa updating the view updates the model. Using `{{address.district}}` does not 2-way data bind. It only outputs the value of the model. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

The button type reset is resetting the model regardless of the disabled property. If you don't want 2-way data binding you can just use `{{address.district}}` as you have mentioned. See: http://jsfiddle.net/K2f7g/1/.